# How to use Codecept with Puppeteer package on PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, codeceptjs

I'm new to both PhpStorm and codecept. I need to test a website using Codecept with Puppeteer package on PhpStorm. Could you please guide??

Answer (score 0):

CodeceptJS is not yet supported in the plaform: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31128

Comment: the link is 10 months old. Are you sure its still not supported?

Comment: Pretty much, otherwise its support would've been announced by the WebStorm team, and the request would've been marked as fixed.

Comment: I found this - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-codeception-framework.html. Haven't tried it yet though.

Comment: It's Codeception, a PHP testing framework, not CodeceptJS.